# What are SingletonMethods and InstanceMethods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, singleton, instance

I see a lot of stuff

```
include ActiveRecord::XXXX::InstanceMethods
extend ActiveRecord::XXXX::SingletonMethods
```

I am unaware of the property or there working, just wanted a easy to understand answer.
if it has a good reason to be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a not-written convention usually adopted when you want to encapsulate features/extensions in a Ruby module intended to be used as a Mixin.

```
module Bar
  def beta
    puts "I'm beta"
  end
end

class Foo
  include Bar

  def alpha
    puts "I'm alpha"
  end
end

Foo.new.beta
# => "I'm beta"
```

Sometimes the Mixin is a simple as providing some instance methods, sometimes else you need to extend the original class with both instance and class methods.
The following syntax in Ruby is invalid.

```
module Bar
  def beta
    puts "I'm beta"
  end

  def self.class_beta
    puts "I'm class-beta"
  end
end

class Foo
  include Bar

  def alpha
    puts "I'm alpha"
  end
end

Foo.new.beta
# => "I'm beta"

Foo.class_beta
# => invalid
```

That said, you can't include a module with method defined with `self`.

For this reason, it's a common pratice to split the module in two submodules and use the `self.included` hook.

```
module Bar

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend         ClassMethod
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def class_beta
      puts "I'm class-beta"
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def beta
      puts "I'm beta"
    end
  end

end

class Foo
  include Bar

  def alpha
    puts "I'm alpha"
  end
end

Foo.new.beta
# => "I'm beta"

Foo.class_beta
# => "I'm class beta"
```

Also, [check out this great](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/) article written by Yehuda Katz.

Comment: It's much more common not to have an `InstanceMethods` module, but to instead just include those methods in the `Bar` module body. What does Rails gain by having an `InstanceMethods` module?

Comment: Ken Bloom: Clarity? I used to do this myself when I was unfamiliar with the idiom

Answer (score 2):

Instance methods are methods you define within a class that are sent to INSTANCES of that class.  Singletom or class methods are methods defined within a class that are sent to the CLASS object.  As a simple example:

```
Class A 
def instance_method
 puts "Hi, I'm an instance method"
end
def self.singleton_method 
  puts "Hi, I'm a singleton method"
end
end
```

you call them like this:

```
singleton:

A.singleton_method

instance_method:

a = A.new
a.instance_method
```